# Background color during resize in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a matplotlib figure inside a `QWidget`, when I resize my window there is a black background visable for a very short time (until the figure is resized).

If the plotting widget is inside a layout, this looks very bad.

Is there any way to change this color?

code:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class Plotwindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Plotwindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.figure.set_facecolor('none')
        plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[1,4,9,16,25])
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Plotwindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

[image: black border]

EDIT:

its the same for (without pyqt):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = plt.figure()
    plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[1,4,9,16,25])
    plt.show()
```

EDIT2:

This seems to be a problem with the version and/or os.
I do not have the problem on Ubuntu 16.04 with matplotlib 2.1.0 and python3 or 1.5.1 and python2.
I only experienced this on windows 7 with matplotlib 2.0.2 and python3.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on windows 8.1.

Comment: what color do you see in that area? (see my edit)

Comment: This is how the pure matplotlib figure looks for me: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8C0G.png). Resizing happens instantly, without any background being shown.

Comment: which version of matplotlib are you using? im using 2.0.2

Comment: I just installed matplotlib 2.1.0 yesterday, but using 2.0.2 before I also never saw anything similar to what you see happening.

Comment: even if you hold that resize thing in the bottom right and wiggle your mouse around? I think when the plots are more complicated the resizing should take more time..

Comment: Yes, even when wiggling with the mouse.

Comment: see the very end of my post, that is a really full figure, you should have some resizing time there..

Comment: Just accept it: You may have this problem. I don't. That doesn't mean that it's not worth investigating, all I wanted to say is that it isn't present naturally for everyone; and hence you might also consider that it is specific to your operating system or something else on your computer.

Comment: ok, I just wanted to be certain before I try other versions or things like that. thanks for your comments